# Convert byte array string back to a string

Tags: c#, string, unicode, arrays

I have a problem with converting a byte array string back to a literal. I am reading a string from a xml file which was converted to a byte array (`Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string)`). I dose not developed the xml export. Now I would like to convert the value back to a string.

For example (note that it is a real string)

"AQwAtADQAMQA5AAwADEAfQAAA==" back to "This is a string!"

I knew that for the encoding `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string)` was used. My fist idea was, to read two values, calculate the byte value and convert them back to a unicode string. Is there any better solution? Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that "==" padding. Is there any chance it is a base64 encoding related?

Comment: I noticed that too. I already checked that with the same could you suggested. But dose not work. I will check that tomorrow again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing this out there in case data came in with base64 encoded.

```
byte[] binaryData;
try {
      binaryData = 
         System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
}
catch (System.ArgumentNullException) {
      //handling error
}

string myString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(binaryData);
```

give it a try.

read more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried that already but sadly the result is not the original input.

Comment: just another quick thought. maybe It's utf8 or utf32 and not unicode?

Comment: I did a huge mistake... I used `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` instead of `Encoding.Unicode.GetString`. Thanks!